# Return List or other Data Structure from Class in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, class, oop

I am trying to create a class in python to return a list of elements such as data types for columns in the data frame.

Following is the class method I have created. I would like to get 3 lists each containing different columns with specified column types such as int, object, and date.

```
class Check_columns:
    """
    :data_frame : a pandas data frame
    :rtype : list
    
    The class takes data frame as input and returns list object 
    containing list of different column types
    """

    import pandas as pd
    
    def __init__(self,data_frame):
        
        self.data_frame = data_frame
        
    def check_types(self):
        
        categorical_columns = self.data_frame.select_dtypes(include='object').columns.tolist()
        
        numeric_columns = self.data_frame.select_dtypes(include=['int32','int64','float32','float64']).columns.tolist()
        
        date_columns = self.data_frame.select_dtypes(include=['datetime64']).columns.tolist()
```

Comment: `return [categorical_columns, numeric_columns, date_columns]`? It returns a list of 3 dataframes.

Comment: Thanks @Stef .. That may work but I want the "class" to generate the lists without explicitly assigning anything. have started entertaining the idea that it may not be possible in "class"